# CORS error Access-Control-Allow-Origin' / wildcard "*" / withCredentials: true , Next 13.5/ axios / Laravel 10

Tags: axios, cors, next.js13, laravel-10

Something strange for me error wise.

- Frontend : Next 13.5
- Backend : Laravel 10
- Domain is registered on Cloudflare /
- frontend on Vercel
- backend standard cPanel

I got this  error

```
`Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'https://api.example.com/sanctum/csrf-cookie' from origin 'https://example.com' has been blocked by CORS policy: Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: The value of the 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header in the response must not be the wildcard '*' when the request's credentials mode is 'include'. The credentials mode of requests initiated by the XMLHttpRequest is controlled by the withCredentials attribute.`
```

My axios.js config:

```
const axios = Axios.create({
    baseURL: process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_BACKEND_URL,
    headers: {
      
        //  'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': 'https://example.com',
        //  'X-Requested-With': 'XMLHttpRequest',
     },
    //withCredentials: false,// corse error
     withCredentials: true, // error 419 
})
```

cors.php

```
'paths' => ['*'],

    'allowed_methods' => ['*'],

    'allowed_origins' => ['https://example.com'],

    'allowed_origins_patterns' => [],

    'allowed_headers' => ['*'],

    'exposed_headers' => [],

    'max_age' => 0,

    'supports_credentials' =>true,
```

session.php :

```
 //'driver' => env('SESSION_DRIVER', 'file'),
        'driver' => env('SESSION_DRIVER', 'database'),
 //'domain' => '.example.com',
     'domain' => 'example.com',
```

I tried all combination with driver and domain.

sanctum.php :

```
'stateful' => explode(',','https://example.com' )
```

Even I got this error, I can find XSRF-TOKEN cookies.
Also if I set withCredentials: false, ('axios.js') i get error 419, of course because I don't have XSRF-TOKEN set.

This is from fresh installed Laravel and Next with Breeze.
Strange thing is that one of my app has same config for last year and something, and it was working great till month ago, same issue.

Any idea how to fix this. Believe me I visit all Google search links and
Cheers

I tried all combination but nothing, clearing Laravel cache after every small change and all others "turn on / of" solutions.

- add custom header in next.config.js for every api link.

```
headers: [
              { key: "Access-Control-Allow-Credentials", value: "true" },
              { key: "Access-Control-Allow-Origin", value: "https://example.com" },
              { key: "Access-Control-Allow-Methods", value: "GET,OPTIONS,PATCH,DELETE,POST,PUT" },
              { key: "Access-Control-Allow-Headers", value: "X-CSRF-Token, X-Requested-With, Accept, Accept-Version, Content-Length, Content-MD5, Content-Type, Date, X-Api-Version" },
    ]
```

- all config files in Laravel are checked.
- Also app is working great on Localhost. No worries there.